# when there are two inputs, how to get the function input, instead of the input from the main body

Tags: function, while-loop

Here is my code, it is copyrighted cited here
Al Sweigart. Invent Your Own Computer Games with Python. August 28, 2015. https://inventwithpython.com/invent4thed/chapter5.html. Accessed December 4, 2020.

```
#import modules
import random
import time

#def functions
def intro():
    guess = int(input("There are two caves, in one is magic treasure and in the other is a 
terrible monster. Hit 1 or 2 to guess. "))
    return guess


def check_cave(guess):
    print("the cave is dank")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("you hear a sound")
    time.sleep(2)
    print("a monster jumps out and opens its jaws and...")
    time.sleep(2)

    friendly_cave = random.randint(1,2)
    if str(guess) == str(friendly_cave):
        print("leaves so you can take the treasure, congratulations!")
    else:
        print("kills you bahahaha")
        print(guess)

#main body of code
play_again = 'no'
guess = int(input("please enter a guess of one or two "))
while play_again == 'yes' or 'y':
    intro()
    check_cave(guess)
    play_again = input("want to play again? yes or no...")
    if play_again == 'yes':
        continue
    else:
        break
```

I expect the code to ask the user for input from the main body of the code, then ask for same input from inside a function later (the function returns the input), I expect the function's returned value to overwrite the original input. but it doesnt. Instead it keeps the original input from outside the function what can I do about this?

Comment: I realize now that it may be unclear I am talking about "check_cave(guess) is the function and the value that isnt going away is guess = int(input(blah blah))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must assign value returned from function `intro()` to a variable:

```py
while play_again == 'yes' or 'y':
    guess = intro() # modified this line
    check_cave(guess)
    play_again = input("want to play again? yes or no...")
    if play_again == 'yes':
        continue
    else:
        break
```